# Html blob 'global_content_block_x' does not exist

Tags: php, cmsmadesimple

I have a recent installation of CMSMS and am not getting help in the forum. It didn't used to be that way, but that's another topic.

Anyway, there's something that's happening again (it was resolved for several months):

```
Html blob 'global_content_block_x' does not exist
```

So all the GCBs don't show up and the site doesn't work without them.

Clearing the cache fixes it temporarily.

The original thread containing the solution to fix this the first time around is now locked, it's located here:

http://forum.cmsmadesimple.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=68368&start=45

What have I done to resolve this:

1. Cleared the cache - works for a day or so
2. Changed CGSmartImage, set
   'Enable Responsive Images:' to No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I occasionally see the same issue with some sites. The latest version of CMS MS includes quick a few changes to caching which appears to be related to the issue. I would recommend you upgrade to this.

http://www.cmsmadesimple.org/2015/01/Announcing-CMS-Made-Simple-1-11-12-Seymour-Norte/